# Get Spotify Artist URI (Python beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, spotify

I am working on a final project for my master's program. :)

One of the tasks is to get the Spotify artist URI of each artist(name), listed in a different dataset ('data'). And afterwards I have to add the URI of each artist to the original dataset.

I have been trying something, but I keep getting [error messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sHuA.jpg)
Is there anyone that might be able to help this Python dummy out?

Thank you!!

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json
headers = {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Bearer BQDXxeeEiSPLfjhRS_IclrK5HsvL7-VD- EGWGQXUTzGw4DZjGPJKfvnAENy9hAtGplHgW7yngchunypC_1EV_b2CKz_qW6AOoh9fp0yG0ckyCArxAGSqa8aMzW4BHeLiBbD8L7HObUS7zX_XK-PGAvrQF_sUFMpIgpMtcsRi',}
  
   for name in data:
        response = requests.get('   https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}', headers=headers) 
        json_data = json.loads(response.text) # Converting response into Python data structure
   print(json_data)
```

Comment: Well "API rate limit exceeded" isn't really a problem with the code as such, it means that Spotify doesn't let you do that many requests in that short amount of time. Your options are either slowing down the script so that it stays below the limits, or asking Spotify to raise the limits (which would probably require paying money.)

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it's because you have certain limitations as of using a free API. Few APIs have it like 50 per day while the others as 500 per day, but ultimately you would be able to use it again the next day, whereas one other option is you could try creating new API credentials in which case it should work fine the same day itself.

P.S: Came across this question as I'm working on a similar project where I need to get URI of the Artist from Spotify without having to manually copy the URI of Artist from Spotify, still wondering if there is a way to do it without using selenium since the app that am building is going to be a desktop app itself.